# os.listdir() lists data files but the corresponding assertion fails

Tags: python, assertion, python-os, listdir

I have the following code which throws an assertion error. `os.listdir()` lists my data files but there is still an assertion error.

```
import os
PATH_TO_FOLDER = 'LOCAL PATH TO MY DATA'
assert 'data' in os.listdir(PATH_TO_FOLDER)
import sys
sys.path.append('..')
```

Comment: Why do you want to `assert 'data' in os.listdir(PATH_TO_FOLDER)`? Is it intended? If so, the problem may simply be that `'data'` is not a directory in your `PATH_TO_FOLDER`.

Comment: What is the output of ``print('data' in os.listdir(PATH_TO_FOLDER))``?

Comment: Please specify the dirs and files as well. I want to see how are you using paths.

Comment: Can you explain what exact you want..?

Comment: @Anakhand you are right sir. Thank you so much

Comment: @DocDriven the output of the print statement is false

Comment: @Anakhand I wish to know why the assertion is failing, I have updated my assert statement to check for the folder name in my path. I guess its case sensitive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was asking you to what the statement `'data' in os.listdir(PATH_TO_FOLDER)` evaluates to. This returned False.

Knowing this I can tell you, `assert` works as intended. Assertions are Boolean expressions, depending on whether your statement `'data' in os.listdir(PATH_TO_FOLDER)` is True or False. If it is True, then nothing happens and your code skips to the next line. If False, it raises an `AssertionError`. Assertions are meant to check if certain prerequisites are met.

Coming back to your issue: the error will stop from occuring if you make sure that your path is correct and you have a folder called `data` there. Also note that `os.listdir()` does not check for subfolders recursively.

Comment: It turns out I put the folder name in the path itself and was trying to look for a folder named 'data' inside the specified path. Thanks everyone for their time. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

The assertion error originates from the line

```
assert 'data' in os.listdir(PATH_TO_FOLDER)
```

If that line is intentional, the assertion fails simply because there exists no directory or file named `'data'` in your `PATH_TO_FOLDER` directory.

Comment: I have fixed this but the assertion is still failing. The Path_To_Folder is 'D:\LUNA16\data\subset0'

Comment: @kuldeepkaur So you checked the directory `'D:\LUNA16\data\subset0\data'` exists? If so, is it still giving an `AssertionError`? Or is the `'data'` directory you want to detect `'D:\LUNA16\data'`?

Comment: I checked that the directory exists.

Comment: @kuldeepkaur Try to print out `os.listdir('D:\LUNA16\data\subset0')`. What is its complete output?